# Grafana Panel Display Time Length

Tags: grafana

I am using grafana to display prometheus data but the panel only show the latest 20 minutes data although from grafana.ini, the /var/lib/grafana data will be removed after 24 hours. so could you please help how to show 24 hours data?

#################################### Paths ####################################
[paths]

## Path to where grafana can store temp files, sessions, and the sqlite3 db (if that is used)

;data = /var/lib/grafana

## Temporary files in `data` directory older than given duration will be removed

;temp_data_lifetime = 24h

Thanks,

[panel show example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Ri7.png)

Comment: What about the Prometheus data? Can you certify the data is ok there?

Comment: Prometheus data is correct. which components shall store 24 hours data in Grafana or Prometheus?